# Ember.js StateManager for session management

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently having trouble wrapping my head around using a StateManager to manage which state should be active depending on a session check against a server.  I would have thought having a start state that checks the session and determines whether a signedout or a signedin state should be active would work.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.sessionController = Ember.Object.create({
  signedIn: false,

  isSignedIn: function() {
    return this.signedIn;
  },

  signOut: function() {
    this.signedIn = false;
    App.stateManager.goToState('signedout');
  },

  signIn: function() {
    this.signedIn = true;
    App.stateManager.goToState('signedin');
  }
});

App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
  start: Ember.State.create({
    enter: function(sm) {
      this._super(sm);
      if (App.sessionController.isSignedIn()) {
        sm.goToState('signedin');
      } else {
        sm.goToState('signedout');
      }
    }
  }),

  signedin: Ember.State.create({
    enter: function(sm) {
      this._super(sm);
      console.log('entered signedin state');
    },
    exit: function(sm) {
      this._super(sm);
      console.log('exited signedin state');
    }
  }),

  signedout: Ember.State.create({
    enter: function(sm) {
      this._super(sm);
      console.log('entered signedout state');
    },
    exit: function(sm) {
      this._super(sm);
      console.log('exited signedout state');
    }
  })
});

App.sessionController.signIn();
```

Doing this seems to result in exits not being performed correctly.  So I ask, what is the preferred way (correct as mine is apparently wrong) of handling state of a Ember.js app that requires authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the way you manage initial state: defining a `start` state which has no `exit` method, you do not handle the exit transition.

You could either declare initial state as follow:

```
initialState: 'signedout',
```

instead of declaring the `start` state, or provide an `exit` method on `start` state.

IMO, the better way is to use the `initialState` property, as you avoid code duplication.
To manage the possible already singed in case, you could deal with `App.sessionController.signedIn` flag's initial value in the `init` method of `App.sessionController`...

Comment: I've actually tried with an initial state as well.  The problem arises that the exit process on each other state are not executed.  Only the initial state exit process gets executed.  This means that if I were using a ViewState that the view is not removed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better, I used an initial state as I would have a start state, to dispatch to the correct state upon app load.  This is causing unwanted side effects that I think may be due to using goToState inside the enter process of another state.  I'm just not sure where I should put code that would determine the correct state upon app load.

Comment: As I proposed to you in the answer, I think the `App.sessionController.init` method is a good place for this setup, as you are initializing the session controller's internal state.